# Chain rule proof from Wikipedia: references?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I am looking for a reference where the proof of the chain rule is given like in Wikipedia ("[first proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#First_proof)"). A standard real analysis book would be good, even better would be a paper where this proof was discussed (maybe the first time).

Since wikipedia may change here is a quote from the proof:

> One proof of the chain rule begins with the definition of the
>   derivative:
>
> $$(f \circ g)'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{x - a}.$$
>
> Assume for the moment that $g(x$) does not equal $g(a$) for any $x$
>   near $a$. Then the previous expression is equal to the product of two
>   factors:
>
> $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x) - g(a)} \cdot
> \frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x - a}.$$
>
> When $g$ oscillates near $a$, then it might happen that no matter how
>   close one gets to $a$, there is always an even closer $x$ such that
>   $g(x)$ equals $g(a)$. [...]
>
> Whenever this happens, the above expression is undefined because it
>   involves division by zero.  To work around this, introduce a function
>   $Q$ as follows:
>
> $$ \begin{equation} Q(y) = \begin{cases} \frac{f(y) - f(g(a))}{y -
> g(a)}, & y \neq g(a), \\ f'(g(a)), & y = g(a). \end{cases}
> \end{equation} $$
>
> We will show that the difference quotient for $f \circ g$ is always
>   equal to:
>
> $$Q(g(x)) \cdot \frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x - a}.$$
>
> Whenever $g(x)$ is not equal to $g(a)$, this is clear because the
>   factors of $g(x) − g(a)$ cancel.  When $g(x)$ equals $g(a)$, then the
>   difference quotient for $f  \circ g$ is zero because $f(g(x))$ equals
>   $f(g(a))$, and the above product is zero because it equals $f'(g(a))$
>   times zero.  So the above product is always equal to the difference
>   quotient, and to show that the derivative of $f \circ g$ at $a$ exists
>   and to determine its value, we need only show that the limit as $x$
>   goes to $a$ of the above product exists and determine its value.
>
> To do this, recall that the limit of a product exists if the limits of
>   its factors exist.  When this happens, the limit of the product of
>   these two factors will equal the product of the limits of the factors.
>   The two factors are $Q(g(x))$ and $(g(x) − g(a)) / (x − a)$.  The
>   latter is the difference quotient for $g$ at $a$, and because $g$ is
>   differentiable at $a$ by assumption, its limit as $x$ tends to $a$
>   exists and equals $g'(a)$.
>
> It remains to study $Q(g(x))$.  $Q$ is defined wherever $f$ is. 
>   Furthermore, because $f$ is differentiable at $g(a)$ by assumption,
>   $Q$ is continuous at $g(a)$.  $g$ is continuous at $a$ because it is
>   differentiable at $a$, and therefore $Q \circ g$ is continuous at $a$.
>   So its limit as $x$ goes to $a$ exists and equals $Q(g(a))$, which is
>   $f'(g(a))$.
>
> This shows that the limits of both factors exist and that they equal
>   $f'(g(a))$ and $g'(a)$, respectively.  Therefore the derivative of $f
> \circ g$ at $a$ exists and equals $f'(g(a)) g'(a)$.

Comment: *Introduction to Analysis* by Rosenlicht covers this topic.

Comment: I think the discussion in Section 7.3 of *Elementary Real Analysis* will help too.  My co-author wrote that section.  You can get a free PDF at this link:   classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf